# How to open a jQuery Facebox after validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I want to open a facebox modal after some javascript validation. I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="facebox.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
function validatePage()
{
  if(document.getElementById('username').value == '')
  {
        alert('Please enter Username');
        return false;
  }

  //My Code should go here
}
```

Markup:

```
<a href="pagename.php" rel="facebox" onclick="javascript:validatePage()">Click Me</a>
```

For some reason the facebox modal does not open...instread the page is opening in a new window.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you requiring jquery as well? facebox seems to be dependent on jquery

Comment: of course..I am using jQuery..my concern is to open a page in modal using facebox after some javascript validation...

Answer (score 1):

Is your onclick overriding the Facebox functionality? I don't know if it would, but that's a thought. Have you tried manually triggering the function instead?

```
function validatePage(e)
{
  if(document.getElementById('username').value == '')
  {
      alert('Please enter Username');
  } else {
      $.facebox({ajax: $(e).attr("href")});
  }
  return false;
}
```

I just passed the element to the function, to make that extend to other things. You'd just say `"javascript:validatePage(this)"` in your onclick.

Comment: And you'd remove the facebox rel, if you did that. I presume.

Comment: Oh also if you're using jQuery you can just say $("#username").val() instead of the whole document.getElementById('username').value thing. Just sayin'.

Comment: No problem! Would you mind voting it up, or if it's correct, marking it as the correct answer?